# React Js - Unable to enter value in Input Field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, icallbackeventhandler

I appreciate all of your idea in advance. My problem here is the input field of the email is not updating. Can anyone give me a solution?

```js
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Enter Email "
    onChange={this.emailHandle}
    value={this.state.email}
/>
```

Event handler for the above input field is here:

```js
emailHandle = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value !== "undefined") {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
        if (pattern.test(e.target.value)) {
            console.log(e.target.value);
            this.setState({ email: e.target.value })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually see console logs or is there none?

Comment: Did you remove condition block and checked if only `setState` is working?

Comment: Thanks, Hirasawa Yui  and  development-ninja  @Matthew Brooks suggestion worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the initial value of your component state? For one, if you're not initializing the email property on state to be an empty string, and it's undefined, you're blocking that state from ever updating with your undefined check. But you have a bigger problem than that. You're testing to see if the value of the input matches your email regex pattern. That won't ever work if you use that check to block setting state. `onChange` is going to fire every time the input value changes, and that means it's going to change one character at a time. So what's happening is the user types a character, the `onChange` fires, but it doesn't match your pattern, and you don't update state.

What you want to do is always update state and then handle this as validation to block *submitting* the form. Or you could show an error of some kind, but you need to always call `setState` with the new value on `e.target.value`.

Answer (score 3):

The `onChange` event will never be validate by the regex cause it is called on each key typed. So you start typing `andy@gmail.com`, with the `a` but `a` does not pass the regex... so the state is not updated... so it's like you didn't type `a`.